# "Unable to Preview the report" in SSRS report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, report, preview

I am creating SSRS report using AX query, but while click the preview button in design node, I encounter a problem:

> Unable to Preview the report, install the business intelligence development studio feature of Microsoft Sql server

but we already installed those tools server side. If anyone knows the solution please tell me.

Answer (score 1):

[Business Intelligence Development Studio (BIDS)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173745%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) is not a server-side install, it is required to be installed on the developer's workstation.

Install BIDS on the development workstation for integration with Visual Studio, or take a look at [Report Builder 3.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173745%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).